# Remove locked questions from the delete tools

Tags: feature-request, locked-posts, 10k-tools

Actually in the [delete tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) there is a question at the very top that we cannot delete because [it was locked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2403816/8620333).

> [image]

I know that non deletable posts aren't something new there and it's ok since they can become deletable if they are donwvoted but it's not the case of locked posts so please remove them. It's useless to have them there.

<sup>PS: I don't want to open a discussion around the locked post</sup>

Comment: I *suspect* that we can fix this problem by mods just purging delete votes before applying a lock. Let me experiment. (Edit: Oops. Makyen already did this experiment...)

Comment: I resolved the issue with this specific question by clearing the delete-votes which were on the question by deleting the question and then undeleting it. In order to prevent this from happening, when locking a post, the moderator needs to remember to delete and undelete the post, if it has any pending delete-votes.